# Python: how to calculate the longest distance within an area

Tags: python, shapefile

I am trying to calculate the longest distance within each area in a shapefile. Is there any package to do the calculation?

The shapefile is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f5xd4l11ojvhpsl/India-Districts-2011Census.shp?dl=0).

I only figured out how to load the file so far.

```
import geopandas as gp
shape = gp.GeoDataFrame.from_file("India-Districts-2011Census.shp")
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the longest distance?" Do you mean the longest straight line from one side of the shape to the other? Can the line leave the inside of the shape temporarily? Do you mean the perimeter? Does the line have to be near the center of the shape?

Comment: If not too large, you could calculate the convex hull, and use that as a subset of points to calculate the largest line within the shape.

Comment: @Temba, I meant the longest straight line from one side of the shape to the other. The line shouldn't leave the inside of the shape.